# What object can I serialize in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

I'm using `serialize :my_array, Array` and `serialize :my_hash, Hash` quite happily to store settings and arrays in the database conveniently.

Which other objects can I use this way? I know I can use `Struct` and `OpenStruct` for instance, but how would I know if an object can be serialized this way with ActiveRecord? For instance, how do I know if I can use the class `Set` (which should have been called `UniqArray`, mind you) this way?

Answer (score 2):

This code determines a coder for serialization in Rails' `serialize` method:

```
 if [:load, :dump].all? { |x| class_name.respond_to?(x) }
   class_name
 else
   Coders::YAMLColumn.new(class_name)
 end
```

That means in short: a `Object` can be serialized if the `Object` itself has the methods `load` and `dump`. Or if `YAML` can `load` and `dump` the `Object`. Check it this way:

```
object == YAML.load(YAML.dump(object))  # with require 'yaml' in irb
```

Answer (score 2):

Serializing in AR uses Psych for dumping instances into yaml string.

Psych in turn knows how to serialize all objects inherited from Object (it's almost all objects in Ruby).

In general case, Psych takes all instance variables of object and dumps those as yaml fields.

There are also special cases for dumping several classes, such as `Array`, `Class`, `Date`, `DateTime`, `Exception`, `FalseClass`, `Float`, `Hash`, `Integer`, `Module`, `NilClass`, `Range`, `Rational`, `Regexp`, `String`, `Struct`, `Symbol`, `Time`, `TrueClass`, and some other rarely used.

As example, if we have `class UniqArray < Set`, and instance `UniqArray.new([1,2,3])` - dumped string will be `"--- !ruby/object:UniqArray\nhash:\n  1: true\n  2: true\n  3: true\n"` (where `hash` is an instance variable name which implements set store)